# Any way or ideas to protect or sign source code?

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, sign, lib

This is probably a strange question. My project involves a few other people that need to work on the code too. I'm not sure how careful they would be with it and I don't want it to leak. For this reason I split it into 2 parts, one is in the form of a library, the rest just plain source code. There is one other guy that needs everything so he also has the source to the library. I don't want this guy to make any changes to the library. I put in a version number that gets printed when everything is running but I have no way of knowing (from looking at logs) if the library was authentic (from me only).

I was hoping there is some way I can use a public-private-key signature or something like this but against what? I probably can't just calculate an MD5 hash either because the linker probably puts the library function in different places all the time.
I realize it's probably not feasible to sign and verify source code but I would be curious to hear if anybody has any ideas.

Comment: Put an authentication/verification function into your version of the source code that only you know about?

Comment: Sure you can sign it. You can use openssl and sign with HMAC in case you want to be the only one to both sign and verify or with some RSA scheme if you want others to be able to verify it. But both methods are not any better in terms of changing than your MD5 proposition

Comment: If that "other" guy is not supposed to change the library, then I don't see a reason to give him it in a form of sources anyway

Comment: Code signing is a feature of `git` [maybe with some extensions]. Take a look at: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work `github` also has extensions ("pull requests") that allow changes to be reviewed and accepted and rejected. The `gerrit` extension for `git` may be what you want. It requires others to accept/approve/signoff on commits before they are actually commited. The linux kernel submission process allows for signing. `git` was created for kernel development. They're a good example of how to do things.

Comment: Use a source code control system (like git, many others) - you can then see who changed what.

Comment: Q: Your question *ISN'T* about the source, is it?  That's easy to verify with a VCS (like Git).  Q: Your question is "How do I ensure 'the other guy' is running a lib/exec built from unaltered source?", correct?  You're looking for a *RUNTIME* check, correct?

Comment: paulsm4  you are correct.

Comment: If you can control the CI pipeline (the automated build), then you can split your .cpp into parts, and restrict read/write access to specific files. If a developer wants to build, they can use your pipeline (admittedly slower, but its a tradeoff for safety)

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the [VCS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/version-control-systems/) (version control systems) listed [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/the-top-7-open-source-version-control-systems/).

By my experience you can use [Github](https://github.com/), it is easy to work with.